# Do calculations on datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I've been trying the following date&time operations:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("1899-12-30 19:45:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
b = datetime.datetime.strptime("1899-12-30 12:42:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
print (a-b)
print (a/b)
```

a-b works super, but a/b crashes: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'

Any ideas on how I can calculate relations between date&time-values? Do I need to explicitly first calculate the seconds in each variable a and b, or is there a shorter short cut?

And if I need to calculate seconds. How do I do it? I've tried

```
s = a.total_seconds()
which gives: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

(I'm using Python 3.3)

Comment: What is your expected output when dividing two dates?

Comment: It's calculating race times, e.g. b uses 30% more time than a (so the date really isn't important)

Comment: You can't really divide dates. You can divide date *intervals*, so use `datetime.timedelta`; I think that has `total_seconds` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime.timedelta support divide operate as shown in the [manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

So, I think you should do is:

1. Minuse the datetime.datetime.min `a_interval = a - datetime.datetime.min`, `b_interval = b - datetime.datetime.min`
2. Start calculate: `print(a_interval - b_interval)` and `print(a_interval / b_interval)`

I hope this can help you

Comment: This worked, when changing the datetime.datetime.min with the actual start date! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You  have to make the difference between [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) (which is an actual date and time, for example "1899-12-30 19:45:00") and [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) (which is a period, for example "1 hour"). 
Note that your   `a-b` substraction of two datetimes will result in a timedelta.

If you're calculating race times, you have to specify the start time of the race (how would you know, anyway, how long the race lasted). Then you can do

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.strptime("1899-12-30 12:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # whatever the start time is
a = datetime.datetime.strptime("1899-12-30 19:45:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
b = datetime.datetime.strptime("1899-12-30 12:42:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
print (a-b)  # it will give you the timedelta difference between racer "a" and racer "b" 
print (a-start).total_seconds()/(b-start).total_seconds() # it will give you the ratio between "a" and "b" race times
```

Division is not defined for datetimes. But timedelta objects have `total_seconds()` which give you a number (the length of period in seconds), and you can divide numbers.

---

In Python 3.x [print is a function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) and thus needs parentheses, solving the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'`:

```
print ((a-start).total_seconds()/(b-start).total_seconds())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was one of the things I tried myself, but I get the following message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: OP uses Python 3 where the division `datetime / timedelta` *is* defined. Your code works on Python 2 too.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: thanks, edited the answer to remove the misleading part. It seems I'm losing too much with using Python 2...

Comment: @leeladam: Thanks a lot! But I still get the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: @Enthuziast: `print` needs extra parentheses in Python 3.x: `print ((a-start).total_seconds()/(b-start).total_seconds())`

Answer (score 0):

Number of seconds from zero date:

```
x = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)

print (a-x).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get the following message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'